# Binding to the same property on multiple windows doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I ran into a quite confusing problem when developing a multi-window wpf application.

There are two windows, MainWindow and SecondWindow. The code of both is pretty simple:
MainWindow:

```
<Button Content="Change Property to 5" Click="ChangeProperty" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

SecondWindow:

```
<Label Content="{Binding InstanceOfMyClass.value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"></Label>
```

The code behind the second Window is untouched, the code behind the first window is the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SecondWindow w;
    ViewModel vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel() { InstanceOfMyClass = new MyClass() { value = 3 } };
        w = new SecondWindow() { DataContext = vm };
        w.Show();
    }

    private void ChangeProperty(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.InstanceOfMyClass.value = 7;
    }
}
```

And the view model class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyClass _instance;
    public MyClass InstanceOfMyClass 
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
        set
        {
            _instance = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InstanceOfMyClass");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
class MyClass
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}
```

I expected the text block to change its text to 5 when I click the button. 
The number "3" is correctly loaded on startup. The window also refreshes when I create a new instance of `MyClass` and set it as `InstanceOfMyClass` in my `ViewModel`.

But when I hit the button - or, even stranger, when I temporarily store `InstanceOfMyClass`, set it to `null` and reassign it with the saved variable - nothing happens.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `MyClass` and try again. In `ChangeProperty` you change the `value` property, that doesn't notify the view about the change.

Or you can also try rewriting your `ChangeProperty` to the following:

```
vm.InstanceOfMyClass = new MyClass() { value = 7 };
```

Both of these approaches should fix the problem as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks! So it had nothing to do with the second window.